# How to provide authentication in Azure Application like Single sign in

Tags: azure, authentication, iframe, azure-active-directory, chatbot

I have Created a Azure chatbot with Luis as a result i am getting the Iframe URL and pasted it into my website.

I want my i frame to be secure like if someone copy paste my iframe URL and pasted it into another website it will not work . It should ask some Authentication.

How can i protected my Iframe url with Azure Authentication. Is there any way Azure provide to us

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can secure your `iframe` so that none can stole it. You can implement token on your web chat bot.

`If you can execute a server-to-server request to exchange your web chat secret for a temporary token, and if you want to make it difficult for other developers to embed your bot in their websites` then you can try following way.

Please refer below like for complete implementation

1. [Official Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)
2. [Complete  Implementation](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/01/using-webchat-with-azure-bot-services-authentication/)

Hope that would help.